# Создание таблицы с тремя уровнями заголовков

Tags: pandas, dataframe, multi-index

Проблема такая, что хотелось бы получать таблицу с тремя уровнями заголовка, а когда добавляешь 3-й уровень, то названия 2-х уровней объединяются, и всё равно выходит 2 уровня. Вот пример:

```
import pandas as pd
df2 = pd.DataFrame(np.array([[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6], [7, 8, 9]]),
                   columns=['c', 'a', 'b'])

head_tolist_1=['H','K','L']
head_tolist_2=['N','Q','M']

df2.columns = pd.MultiIndex.from_tuples(zip(head_tolist_1,df2.columns))
df2.columns = pd.MultiIndex.from_tuples(zip(head_tolist_2,df2.columns))

print(df2.head(5))
```

Результат:

```
    N      Q      M
  (H, c) (K, a) (L, b)
0      1      2      3
1      4      5      6
2      7      8      9
```

А надо:

```
    N      Q      M
    H      K      L
    с      b      a
0   1      2      3
1   4      5      6
2   7      8      9
```

Когда делаешь таблицы через pivot_table 3 уровня же получается, а таким способом почему то нет...
Может есть какая-то тонкость тут? или другие варианты?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Добавьте в `zip()` сразу три списка

```
df2.columns = pd.MultiIndex.from_tuples(zip(head_tolist_2,head_tolist_1,df2.columns))
```

```
   N  Q  M
   H  K  L
   c  a  b
0  1  2  3
1  4  5  6
2  7  8  9
```

Comment: сколько я всего перепробовал, а ответ бы так близко :) спасибо!