# Сделать двойное именование столбцов датафрейма/ перенести имена столбцов в строку

Tags: python, dataframe

Есть задача создать двойное наименования столбцов датафрейма. Массив представляет собой результат опроса, где именем столбца является формулировка вопроса. Использовать это имя при манируляциях с данными неудобно, но и терять нельзя - эти имена нужны при построении таблиц и диаграмм.
Пришла идея переименовать столбцы, а длинные имена перенести в нулевую строку массива, чтобы при необходимости обращаться к ним. Но не приходит идей, как это правильно сделать и как потом обращаться к строке как источнику подписей в таблицах и диаграммах. Буду признательна за идеи.

Comment: Строка кажется лишней заморочкой. Можно сохранить изначальные названия столбцов в словарь. Пары старое и новое название, на время работы переименовать, а после из этого же словаря вернуть обратно. Причём словарь отработает даже если колонки будут перемещаться и удаляться.

Comment: Можете легко это сделать, хоть с [тройными](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1460991/%d0%a1%d0%be%d0%b7%d0%b4%d0%b0%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b5-%d1%82%d0%b0%d0%b1%d0%bb%d0%b8%d1%86%d1%8b-%d1%81-%d1%82%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%bc%d1%8f-%d1%83%d1%80%d0%be%d0%b2%d0%bd%d1%8f%d0%bc%d0%b8-%d0%b7%d0%b0%d0%b3%d0%be%d0%bb%d0%be%d0%b2%d0%ba%d0%be%d0%b2/1461012#1461012)

Comment: О, здорово! А не подскажете, можно ли обращаться к какому-то из дополнительных уровней заголовков при создании, например, таблицы?